# MYSQL_FIELD_NAME Equlent to SQL SERVER

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Converting my code from mysql to SQL server (SQLsrv), but having issue founding the equlent to mysql_field_name as used here:

```
foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
{
    if($col['c']=='')
    {
        if(is_string($col['f']))
            $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
        else
            $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst(mysql_field_name($res,$col['f']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be `sqlsrv_get_field()`. See below MSDN document (link) for documentation and code samples:

[sqlsrv_get_field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296207(v=SQL.90).aspx)

Syntax:

```
sqlsrv_get_field( resource $stmt, int $fieldIndex)
```

Taken from MSDN (A sample usage):

```
$tsql = "SELECT ReviewerName, Comments 
         FROM Production.ProductReview
         WHERE ProductReviewID=1";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Make the first row of the result set available for reading. */
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false )
{
     echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
echo "$name: ";
```